# Pandas groupby divide consecutive rows in some particular groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id variable year value
1     a      20   1.1
1     a      21   1.1
1     a      22   1.2
2     a      20   0.5
2     a      21   0.3
2     a      22   0.1
1     b      20   1.1
1     b      21   1.1
1     b      22   1.2
2     b      20   0.5
2     b      21   0.3
2     b      22   0.1
```

Now I want to groupby `id` and `variable` and update `value` column by dividing consecutive rows' values, for the groups where `variable` is a. I want to keep the rest of the groups as it is.

```
id variable year value
1     a      20   
1     a      21   1
1     a      22   1.09
2     a      20   
2     a      21   0.6
2     a      22   0.33
1     b      20   1.1
1     b      21   1.1
1     b      22   1.2
2     b      20   0.5
2     b      21   0.3
2     b      22   0.1
```

And finally as for groups with `variable` a, the 2020 value isn't available, I want to copy 2021 value in 2020.

```
id variable year value
1     a      20   1
1     a      21   1
1     a      22   1.09
2     a      20   0.6
2     a      21   0.6
2     a      22   0.33
1     b      20   1.1
1     b      21   1.1
1     b      22   1.2
2     b      20   0.5
2     b      21   0.3
2     b      22   0.1
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `pct_change`

```
s=1+df.groupby(['id','variable']).value.pct_change().bfill()
df.loc[df.variable=='a','value']=s
df
Out[52]: 
    id variable  year     value
0    1        a    20  1.000000
1    1        a    21  1.000000
2    1        a    22  1.090909
3    2        a    20  0.600000
4    2        a    21  0.600000
5    2        a    22  0.333333
6    1        b    20  1.100000
7    1        b    21  1.100000
8    1        b    22  1.200000
9    2        b    20  0.500000
10   2        b    21  0.300000
11   2        b    22  0.100000
```

Comment: a nice answer :) +1

Comment: @YOBEN_S shouldn't you sort it first